# Asynchronous HttpRequest using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 in ASP

Tags: asynchronous, asp-classic, event-handling, httprequest

I was trying to make LINK FINDER and **facing 2 issue**

*Issue 1 (Resolved)* :: Unable to get url of redirected page

This was resolved [REFERNCE LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358654/serverxmlhttp-request-returing-data-but-not-returning-url-of-final-page-after-30) by using **WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1**

*Issue 2 (Unsolved)* :: unable to use WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 object **EVENTS** Or no callback to asynchronous request

***Synchronous request code***

```
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.open "GET", url, FALSE
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send PostData
```

This is working fine but if I have multuple request , then its taking to much time.

I have tried following ***Asynchronous request code*** but get error

```
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.open "GET", url, TRUE
req.OnReadyStateChange = GetRef("req_OnReadyStateChange")
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send PostData

Function req_OnReadyStateChange
   ' do something
End Function
```

*Code 1*

```
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1","req_")
req.open "GET", url, TRUE
Function req__OnResponseFinished
  ' do something
End Function
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send PostData
```

***ERROR - The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'CreateObject'***

*Code 2*

```
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.open "GET", url, TRUE
req.OnResponseFinished = GetRef("req_OnResponseFinished")
Function req_OnResponseFinished
   ' do something
End Function
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send PostData
```

***ERROR : Object doesn't support this property or method: 'req.OnResponseFinished***

*Code 3*

```
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.open "GET", url, TRUE
req.OnReadyStateChange = GetRef("req_OnReadyStateChange")
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send PostData
 Function req_OnReadyStateChange
   ' do something
End Function
```

> In microsoft documentation, they have referred
>   *WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1* have 4 event.

1. OnError
2. OnResponseDataAvailable
3. OnResponseFinished
4. OnResponseStart

But i didn't got example of how to use this event, nor i am able to use these event in ASP.

Hope for quick response...

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using a Sub instead of a function for that "req_OnReadyStateChange"?

by the way i am using the MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP object and this is working fine. is there any reason why you are using this WinHttp API?

example with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP:

```
<%
dim url : url = "http://localhost"
dim XmlHttp : set XmlHttp = server.createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
XmlHttp.onreadystatechange = getRef("doHttpReadyStateChange")
XmlHttp.open "GET", url, true
XmlHttp.send()

sub doHttpReadyStateChange
    response.write XmlHttp.readyState
    response.write "<br>"

    select case XmlHttp.readyState
        case 0  'UNINITIALIZED

        case 1  'LOADING

        case 2  'LOADED

        case 3  'INTERACTIVE

        case 4  'COMPLETED
            response.write "Done"
    end select
end sub
%>
```

Comment: Yes , I need final URL after redirection thats why i am using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1.

for more info you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358654/serverxmlhttp-request-returing-data-but-not-returning-url-of-final-page-after-30

Comment: @Dr_Dang ok and have you tried using a Sub instead of a function for the OnReadyStateChange Event?